# Adding save pdf option GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

A year ago with the help of another user I was able to use google app script to take the form responses and email a pdf (code below)

I now need to save the pdf to a specific folder
I also need to add a link to the saved pdf within the google sheet. Is this possible?

````
var docTemplate = "doc ID"; 
var docName = "Vehicle check with images";

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
    var width = 300; // Please set this.
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
    var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
    var w = img.getWidth();
    var h = img.getHeight();
    img.setWidth(width);
    img.setHeight(width * h / w);
  }

  //Get information from form and set as variables
  var email_address = "myemailaddress@here.com";
  var vehicle_vrn = e.values[1];
  var front_desc = e.values[2];
  var front_image = e.values[3].split("=")[1];
  var rear_desc = e.values[4];
  var rear_image = e.values[5].split("=")[1];
  var driver_desc = e.values[6];
  var driver_image = e.values[7].split("=")[1];
  var passenger_desc = e.values[8];
  var passenger_image = e.values[9].split("=")[1];

  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName+' for '+vehicle_vrn)
  .getId();
  // Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  // Get the document’s body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getBody();

  copyBody.replaceText('keyVrn', vehicle_vrn);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyFrontdesc', front_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyFrontimage', front_image);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyReardesc', rear_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyRearimage', rear_image);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDriversdesc', driver_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyDriversimage', driver_image);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyPassdesc', passenger_desc);
  replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'keyPassimage', passenger_image);

  copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
  var subject = "sample attachment file";
  var body = "sample text: " + vehicle_vrn + "";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

  DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}```
````

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect, for example, how about putting the script of `SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetId").getSheetByName("sheetName").appendRow([DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId").createFile(pdf).getUrl()])` after `var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");`? By this, the URL of PDF file is appended to the sheet of "sheetName". How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your quick response. Your answer for saving the pdf to a folder is excellent, I was trying something similar but I was wrong.

I was hoping it is possible to get the url for the pdf file that is created and place it within the responses sheet on the next column (it can be a specified column). This is less important but beneficial if it can be done. Thank you for the script you have put above, I will try it out.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to save the PDF data to the specific folder as a file.
- You want to retrieve the URL of the saved PDF file and put it to the specific column of the Spreadsheet.

#### Modification points:

- In order to save the PDF data (in your case, it's a blob.) to the specific folder, you can use `DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId").createFile(pdf)`.
- In order to retrieve the URL of the created file, you can use `getUrl()`.
- In order to put the URL to the specific column of the Spreadsheet.

  - You want to put the value to the next column of the last row.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows. Before you use this modified script, please set the folder ID, Spreadsheet ID and sheet name.

From:

```
copyDoc.saveAndClose();
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
```

To:

```
copyDoc.saveAndClose();
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
var url = DriveApp.getFolderById("###folderId###").createFile(pdf).getUrl();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###spreadsheetId###").getSheetByName("###sheetName###");
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn() + 1).setValue(url);
```

- When you run the script, `pdf` is created to the folder `###folderId###` as a file, and `url` is put to the next column of the last row of the sheet `###sheetName###` on the Spreadsheet `###spreadsheetId###`.

#### Note:

- If you want to give the filename of PDF file, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf").setName("###filename###");
    ```

#### References:

- [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)
- [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geturl)
- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Steve Haddley Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.